# AutoFixture UnitTest Parameter Setup

Tags: c#, unit-testing, autofixture

How can I setup AutoFixture for the following unit test:

```
[Theory, ... ] // <- what goes here? 
public void MyTest(int param1, string param2)
{
  ...
}
```

The first parameter can take randomly generated integers so AutoFixture naturally fits.
The second one cannot be the same way. I need the second one to take the values from a dynamically generated list of values that is not known at compile time. I need to tell that to AutoFixture but I do not know how.

EDIT:

In my specific scenario what I need is that the string param be a property name of some type. I would like to say to AutoFixtue: "Hey, for param2, take a random string from this list where the list is myType.GetPropertyNames().

Does AutoFixture support this scenario?

Answer (score 1):

If you need random values, just use `[AutoData]`:

```
[Theory, AutoData]
public void MyTest(int param1, string param2)
{
  ...
}
```

If you need some predefined test data you can use [`[InlineAutoData]`](https://github.com/AutoFixture/AutoFixture/wiki/Cheat-Sheet#inline-autodata-theories). In the sample below the `string` parameter `param1` will get values specified in the attribute. The `int` parameter `param2` will always be random:

```
[Theory]
[InlineAutoData("predefined_string_1")]
[InlineAutoData("predefined_string_2")]
public void MyTest(string param1, int param2)
{
  ...
}
```

Comment: But you need to know the values at compile time. What if the "predefined" strings are the property names of some type? I need to be able to pass valid strings to my test method without hard code them. Is this possible?

Comment: > "But you need to know the values at compile time."

Exactly. If you want to test some behavior and random data are not sufficient, you _need_ to know the values at compile time. Otherwise, how will you check your system behaves correctly if the input test data are not specified?

Comment: I do not feel that it has to be either completely random or completely hard coded values. I would like to pass test data that is somehow formatted for my test to make sense. In my specific scenario what I need is that the string param be a property name of some type. I would like to say to AutoFixtue: "hey, for param2, take a random string from this list where the list is myType.GetPropertyNames()".